# Background image not showing in iPhone

Tags: html, css

I have found that my background image is not showing up on iPhone. But, it's perfectly working in android devices. Please help me in this regard. I'm making use of parallax effect.

HTML section:

```
<section id="showcase">
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="home-search p-5">
    <div class="overlay p-5">
```

CSS section:

```
 #showcase {
  background: url(../img/showcase.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed/cover ;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 650px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 6rem; }

  #showcase .home-search {
    min-height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px; }
  #showcase .overlay {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this.

```css
#showcase {
  background: url(../img/showcase.jpg);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:top center;
   background-size:cover;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 650px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 6rem; }
```